# jQuery get div content

Tags: jquery, find

I have the following div structure, but this structure is changing

```
<div class="rt-container">
    <div class="rt-block">
        <div id="rt-mainbody">
            <div id="responseMessage">Welcome bogyoro. Now you are loged in.</div>
            <div id="responseErrorMessage">5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using the following code to get the responseMessage content:

```
var div = logReg.query("<div>").html(msg);
var message = div.children('#responseMessage').html();
var isValid = div.children('#responseErrorMessage').html();
if(isValid == null)
{
    message = div.find('#responseMessage').html();
    isValid = div.find('#responseErrorMessage').html();
}
```

But the isValid is null.

Update:

```
var logReg = {};
logReg.query = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

Comment: What is `logReg`? What is `query`?

Comment: a quick suggestion: you don't need the `div.find`, just use: `$('#responseMessage').html()` (you're calling the ID, it's unique.

Comment: you're checking if the errorMessage exists? or if it has something there?

Comment: Ok, but the msg is a ajax response, and I don't have access in the server side.

Comment: even so, an ID is and ID, and that method has to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var isValid = div.children('#responseErrorMessage').html();

if (isValid == null) { }
```

Will always result in false. If the element exists, that is.

If an element is empty, the return will be an empty string. Try out `if (isValid == "") { }` instead.

Comment: I was just posting the same :) also I think the logic in the OP code is somehow wrong, the isValid Var will containg different objects, that's odd.

Comment: His logic doesn't make sense. He declares a var to hold the error text. He then tries to see if it's not empty, and if it's not, he re-declares it. Weird.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get the html of an element having an id, then you can simply use the id selector.

```
$("#responseMessage").html();
```

Comment: Ok, but the msg is a ajax response, and I don't have access in the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this?

```
var message = logReg.query('#responseMessage').html();  
var isValid = logReg.query('#responseErrorMessage').html();
```

The top line of your code is problematic. It'll return an entire array of div tags. So when you do div.children('...') you're doing that for the entire list of divs.

Since you have the anchors for the specific elements, just look them up directly.