# hide myclass for which div is not available

Tags: jquery

I have for eg `#test` on many page and in some page the `#test` div is not so I wanted to hide `.myclass` in which `#test` div is not. So I tried the following:

```
var $bs = $('body').find('#test');
    if($bs === 'undefined'){ // but this seems wrong also tried type of $bs === 'undefined'

        $('.myclass').css('display','none');
    }
```

Comment: `$bs` can be an empty set, but it can't be undefined, use `.length` instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487309/jquery-get-div-content

Comment: I'm not sure I like this `$bs` variable naming. Your code shouldn't have a profuse mixture of jQuery and unwrapped DOM elements in it, anyway.. and even it if it did, wrapping a jQuery wrapper is easy and efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do:

```
if(!$bs.length){ 
    $('.myclass').css('display','none');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var $bs = $('#test');
if($bs.length == 0){
    $('.myclass').css('display','none');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

rather than finding element, just check length using .length() function. It will return 0 if the element is not present and then you can write your code for that condition.

```
var $bs = $('#test').length();
if($bs == 0){ 
    $('.myclass').css('display','none');
}
```